# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when using a numpy.bytes_ object in string formatting

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

The code should speak for itself:

```
$ python
Python 3.3.0 (default, Dec 22 2012, 21:02:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> '{}'.format(np.bytes_(b'Hello'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
>>> np.version.version
'1.7.0'
```

Both `str` and `repr` return `"b'Hello'"` on `np.bytes_(b'Hello')`, and I can `print(np.bytes_(b'Hello'))` just fine, but in a format string it falls into a recursion loop.

Am I being stupid or is it indeed what it appears to be, i.e. a problem in `numpy`? Even if it is, I don't quite understand what is happening. Can someone please explain?

I haven't reproduced it with Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `{}` is to call `np.bytes_(b'Hello').__format__()`. It seems there is a bug where `__format__` is calling itself. See this [related ticket](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/385)

Here is a workaround.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:57) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> '{}'.format(np.bytes_(b'Hello'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
>>> '{!s}'.format(np.bytes_(b'Hello'))
"b'Hello'"
>>> '{!r}'.format(np.bytes_(b'Hello'))
"b'Hello'"
```